# RoR Validating dependent models but not stopping parent if dependent validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a frustratingly simple problem, but it has vexed me.

I have two models, comments and notes. A comment can have one or no notes. Notes have only a text field. They have a shared form with an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` field.

At the moment, every time a comment is made, it creates an associated blank note. I only want the note to be created if something is entered in the note's text field. I don't want a gagillion blank notes.

I suspect this is a trivial problem, but I am damned if I can solve it.

I tried `validates :text, presence: true`, on note but, when it fails, it prevents the parent comment from being created, which is not what is wanted. Grrr.

**note.rb**

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :comment
    validates :text, presence: true
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   ...
  has_one :note, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :note
```

**comment/_form.html.erb**

```
    <%= form.fields_for :note do |note_form| %>
      Notes<br />
      <%= note_form.text_area :text, cols: 57, rows: 8 %>
    <% end %>`
```

It is, I guess, doing what it is supposed to do. I just don't want it to do that... 
A virtual pint to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

### New answer.

I had a look at your issue and turns out that [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) [NOTE the link is for rails 6, but its same with rails 5] expects additional parameters. One of which is `reject_if`, that means you can pass a proc and if it returns false, the nested record will not save.

So, in your case, you can do the followings

```rb
# app/models/note.rb
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment, optional: true
end

# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :note, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :note, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['text'].blank? }
end
```

Note that,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :note, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['text'].blank? }
```

which will return false if the text on note is blank and in turn avoid saving the blank note record.

I've had a quick test and this works in my rails 5.2 app. \o/

You can refer my bare minimum rails app on github if need be [sameera207/so-question-58599317](https://github.com/sameera207/so-question-58599317)

### Initial answer, doesn't work

<s>Assuming this is rails 5, Try `:inverse_of`</s>

UPDATE: `optional: true` added after the comment by the OP

```rb
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :comment, inverse_of: :notes, , optional: true
    validates :text, presence: true
```

```rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   ...
  has_one :note, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :comment
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :note
```

[This is a very good writeup about :inverse_of](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations/) and it talks about `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which I think the issue you are having

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quickly. Alas, I tried adding the  `:inverse_of` as you kindly suggested but it didn't work. When the note validation fails, it prevents the comment from being saved.

Comment: ah.. One more thing you can do is to make try making the belongs_to optional. Coz from rails 5, `belongs_to` is mandatory by default. (this is assuming you have a nil check validation). I've updated the answer, if that also doesnt work, can you please post the rails console log when you try to save the record

Comment: you are far too kind. I tried - and failed. If I had much hair left I would be tearing it out by now. I have spent hours trawling through the rails documentation, scouring the net, to no avail. I have come up with a really, really ugly kludge. I can't find a way of stopping the note being created so instead as soon as the comment is saved I test for an empty text field and then delete the note. It is incredibly inelegant and not the kind of thing to talk about in polite society, but it does work.

Comment: thanks, you are probably the most polite person I've ever met on SO :). I had a look at your issue again and I updated my answer with a working solution. I personally. think its better than deleting the blank record after create

Comment: Thank you for your persistence. I **hate** my solution. It is ugly and massively inefficient. I will try your much neater one.